# Shopware 6.4.12.0 Stock display in product page

Tags: stock, shopware6

i am new to this website so maybe this question is already asked before.
i am currenlty setting up products using shopware 6, but when it comes to stock its not showing the qty but only a text (in stock), did someone else ahd this problem and does someone have an idea for me to add this.

again i am new to this, so if any info is needed please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to adjust the template of the html page to display that information, take a look at the docs on [how to do that](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/customize-templates).

But this can differ if you use a different theme then the default one. Depending on the theme you use there may be already a configuration for that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry totally forgot about this, as i found the solution for my isseu.
but for the new users, when editing the script i use box standaard html twig

you can add a new block
in my case

{% block component_product_box_STQTY %}

Stock: {{product.stock}}, Central warehouse 1-3 Days</>

{% endblock %}

the {{product.stock}} shows the actual value you have in stock

hope someone can us it